# Is it valid to have multiple headers in the same PHP using if-else conditions?

Tags: php

if want a single PHP file to reirect to different pages according to different conditions say depending on the outcome of a post..

```
if(condition 1) {
    header("Location: page1.php");
    exit;
}
else if(condition 2) {
    header("Location: page2.php");
    exit;
}
else {
    header("Location: page3.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Which problems are you facing?

Comment: That should work as long as no whitespace has been output.

Comment: no problems but unsure if this right

Comment: Yes - you can do that.

Comment: with that, you'd only ever issue one header, because the script aborts at each condition anyways. no, there's nothing wrong with it. gets ugly very quickly, but nothing "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aboslutely!

You might want to make sure the headers haven't been sent first. You can use [`headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) for this

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
  // ...
}
```

A good way to handle this might be

```
function redirect_to($location) {
  if (headers_sent($filename, $line)) {
    trigger_error("Headers already sent in {$filename} on line {$line}", E_USER_ERROR);
  }
  header("Location: {$location}");
  exit;
}

// you can now use it like this
if(condition 1) {
  redirect_to("page1.php");
}
else if(condition 2) {
  redirect_to("page2.php");
}
else {
  redirect_to("page3.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `condition N` `if` statements are valid, there's nothing wrong with having different headers for different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as nothing was outputted before any header() call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work provided you don't echo anything onto the page before calling that function.  You can have as much PHP as you like as long as you don't print anything out upstream of the header function.